# Make carousel scroll only on last visible slide or on click

Tags: jquery, carousel, slick.js

I'm using slick.js to display a gallery using the sync mode which basically uses two slick carousels to imitate the gallery behaviour. When clicking on a slide, the whole carousel autoslides so that the clicked element is at the start of the carousel. I only want the gallery to move forwards when the last visible slide is clicked or when you use the arrow button. For example [FlexSlider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html) has this behaviour. I am using this code for my slick gallery:

```
$('.slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
  dots: true,
  centerMode: false,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  variableWidth: true,
  infinite: false
});
```

You can see the autosliding of slick in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gx6279yu/1/). Does anyone know how to get the same behaviour as FlexSlider for slick?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: try out flexslider its pretty good http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

Comment: I would do that, but unfortunately Flexslider uses the GPL license which makes me distribute my software under the same license terms. And I cannot do that for a commercial project.

Comment: @MatthewDarton Did you end up finding a solution to your problem?